# How to Style JSON Response like a Rich Message

Tags: json, facebook, styling, dialogflow-es

I've been working on a chatapp using a chatbot with custom payloads using DialogFlow, and I've managed to get the responses I want in JSON format.

I'm rather new to coding, and I'm unsure as to how I can take said JSON response, and convert it into a "rich" response like facebook messenger has, by adding buttons, carousels and such.

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Refer https://dialogflow.com/docs/rich-messages

Answer (score 0):

Jerome,

To get started with Facebook Messenger JSON formatting check the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform). Go through the links on the left to familiarize yourself with the request formats.

However an example of what you want to do is as follows:

1. Setup a fulfilment service - which i think you have done already.
2. To send a text payload back from your fulfilment for Messenger these JS samples should work for you

   ```
   module.exports.sendTextMessage = function(message) {
   return {
       data: {
           speech: message, //optional response for dialogflow 
           displayText: message,//optional response for dialogflow
           contextOut: contexts//optional if you need to set context
           facebook: {
               text: message //text to facebook
           }
       }
   };

   module.exports.sendTextMessageAndLocationButton = function(message) {
   return {
       data: {
           speech: message, //optional response for dialogflow 
           displayText: message,//optional response for dialogflow
           contextOut: contexts//optional if you need to set context
           facebook: {
               text: message //text to facebook
               quick_replies: [                        
                   {
                     "content_type":"location"
                   }
               ]
           }
       }
   };
   ```

   You will find more examples in the link above.